# Maintain contiguous index values after deleting rows from a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've a schedule-building application under development that lets the user add activities to a day within a schedule.

I've a schedule table which holds the headline data:

schedule name, length of the schedule in days, id

and an activities table which holds activity id, schedule id and day offset.

The day offset refers to the 'nth' day of the schedule.  I don't need to store specific dates - those are added later when a schedule is added to someone's calendar.

There isn't necessarily an activity for all of the days within a schedule, or indeed any of them.

Question is - I want to be able to delete days from a schedule (and insert n days too for that matter).

For deletion, the user can highlight multiple days within the schedule they're editing.

So on selecting delete I'll have an array of date offsets to remove from the activities table.  That bit is trivial.

My problem is - if I delete day 5, say, from the schedule, day 6 becomes the new day 5; day 7 the new day 6 etc. so I need to update all the affected activity records in the table.

The only way I can think of doing this is ordering the days to be deleted in ascending order, in turn deleting each one then searching for and decrementing all records with a dayoffset value higher than the deleted offset.  Then re-running this query for every day that's being removed.

It feels very inefficient but I can't think of anything better. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `schedule` SET `day` = `day` - number_of_deleted_days WHERE `day` > first_day_deleted;
```

Order doesn't really depend and you can optimize it to work with continuous ranges, but in my knowledge there is not really anything better